# Webview start always in desktop mode

Tags: java, android, android-webview, user-agent, mobile-website

It's two days i can't start my webview directly in mobile mode. When i open the application for the first time starts the webview displays the desktop. My code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); // Request     progress circle
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en)AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); // Show progress circle

        final Activity activity = this;

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                    activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                    if(progress == 100)
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); // Hide progress circle when page loaded
                    activity.setTitle("Title");
                }
            });
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            webview.loadUrl("http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/");
        }


    }
```

Even if i changed the User Agent doesn't work! I tryied every way. I hope in a help from someone, Thanks.

Comment: does the forum have a mobile view alternative or does it have a mobile view ?

Comment: Yes, when i open the website with my phone on bottom of the page there is a "link" to change version to mobile view. Maybe the problem is this.. Maybe the website doesn't recognize the device automatically but you must change the version manually.. Strange..

Comment: did u notice any url changes after u selected the mobile view ?

Comment: edit: I tryied to enter with the stock browser.. the link says: `http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/?mobile=off` .This means that it recognize the device(the query string says `**mobile**=off`) but doesn't start automatically..i think the problem is from the website

Comment: i tried changing the url to `http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/?mobile=on` and the mobile view worked in chrome !!, So i'd advice you to try changing the url to the above.

Comment: yes, it works..But the problem is if i write:`webview.loadUrl("http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/?mobile=on");` The first page open in right mobile view but when i try to navigate inside the forum change again in desktop mode. Only the index page open in mobile version.

Comment: okay, i tried opening it with the mobile=on in my chrome and the website took me as browsing from a mobile device(even the subforums) until i changed the url to mobile=off.

Comment: this is strange..i mean, in web browser it works but in webview not..mmh

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line before loadUrl()**

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Always desktop mode :( i can't belive in... really i tryied everything!!